# PostgreSQL full text search not using index after importing data with COPY

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to make PostgreSQL use an index for prefix searching using full text search. It works fine in general, but only if I create the index AFTER importing the data. Maybe this is some kind of intended behavior, but I do not understand it.

First I create the index and then import the data using the COPY command:

```
CREATE INDEX account_fts_idx ON account
    USING gin(to_tsvector('german', remote_id || ' ' || name || ' ' || street || ' ' || zip || ' ' || city ));
COPY account (id, remote_id, name, street, zip, city ...) FROM '/path/account.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Then I run a PREFIX (maybe that's important) search using the following select statement:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a.id, a.remote_id, a.name, a.street, a.zip, a.city, al.latitude, al.longitude 
FROM account a 
LEFT JOIN account_location al ON al.id = a.id 
WHERE (to_tsvector('german', a.remote_id || ' ' || a.name || ' ' || a.street || ' ' || a.zip || ' ' || a.city) 
@@ (to_tsquery('german', 'hambu:*')))
```

Which results in poor performance, because the index is not being used:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=28.00..3389.97 rows=319 width=94) (actual time=1.685..1237.674 rows=1336 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (a.id = al.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on account a  (cost=0.00..3360.73 rows=319 width=78) (actual time=1.665..1236.589 rows=1336 loops=1)
        Filter: (to_tsvector('german'::regconfig, (((((((((remote_id)::text || ' '::text) || (name)::text) || ' '::text) || (street)::text) || ' '::text) || (zip)::text) || ' '::text) || (city)::text)) @@ '''hambu'':*'::tsquery)
  ->  Hash  (cost=18.00..18.00 rows=800 width=24) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
        ->  Seq Scan on account_location al  (cost=0.00..18.00 rows=800 width=24) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
Total runtime: 1237.928 ms
```

Now comes the strange part: If i drop the index and recreate it using the same CREATE INDEX command, the same SELECT query uses the index and is very fast.

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=61.92..1290.73 rows=1278 width=94) (actual time=0.561..1.918 rows=1336 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (a.id = al.id)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on account a  (cost=33.92..1257.78 rows=1278 width=78) (actual time=0.551..1.442 rows=1336 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('german'::regconfig, (((((((((remote_id)::text || ' '::text) || (name)::text) || ' '::text) || (street)::text) || ' '::text) || (zip)::text) || ' '::text) || (city)::text)) @@ '''hambu'':*'::tsquery)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on account_fts_idx  (cost=0.00..33.60 rows=1278 width=0) (actual time=0.490..0.490 rows=1336 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('german'::regconfig, (((((((((remote_id)::text || ' '::text) || (name)::text) || ' '::text) || (street)::text) || ' '::text) || (zip)::text) || ' '::text) || (city)::text)) @@ '''hambu'':*'::tsquery)
  ->  Hash  (cost=18.00..18.00 rows=800 width=24) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
        ->  Seq Scan on account_location al  (cost=0.00..18.00 rows=800 width=24) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
Total runtime: 2.054 ms
```

So why does the index has to be created after the import?

And more important to me: Will new rows (added normally via INSERT INTO) added to the index?

Comment: Did you run analyze after importing your data?

Comment: No I did not and sadly it not help to do so, but it pointed me into the right direction. I had to run 'ANALYZE account', which according to the docs "completes any pending index insertions" (for GTIN indexes). That helps, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Denis pointed me into the right direction. I looked at the VACUUM, ANALYZE command and found the solution:

> For tables with GIN indexes, VACUUM (in any form) also completes any pending index insertions, by moving pending index entries to the appropriate places in the main GIN index structure. ([PostgreSQL Documentation: VACUUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-vacuum.html))

After running `VACUUM account` the SELECT query uses the index as excpected.